# ggplot + r panel data too much data in graph + interactive points + selecting specific variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

i have some questions if anyone can help.
I have a panel data such as, example:

```
Country Name    Year    GDP    PPP    HHH
USA             1960    7       9      10
Uk              1960    9       10     NA
World           1960    7       5      3
Africa          1960    3       7      NA
```

Few Questions, please bear with me.

I'm using ggplot2 such as

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=GDP, colour=Country Name)) + geom_point()
```

But the graph has too many Country names (about 150 country names) so everything is clustered and unreadable, even if i press zoom through R, its too much for it.

Question 1: How can i omit data such as World and Africa from the ggplot above?

Question 2: Can the points on the graph be interactive, as in, if i touch a point it shows which country? or is there a better graphing package to download, and no i don't have mathematica. Or can i specify different colors for ggplot, but i do have lots of countries to deal with at once.

Question 3: How can i make the graph more readable?

Question 4: what role do the NA values play in R, do they need to be ommitted? do they cause any problems?

Question 5: can i add trend lines to the countries, or do i just add + geom_line()

Question 6: how can i add another variable such as GDP and PPP + year and Country name?

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Q1: by subsetting your data.frame

Q2: [link](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/interactive.html). Yes, you can specify colors. Read the documentation.

Q3: By using a different kind of plot (other than a scatter plot)? By faceting your plot?

Q4: ggplot2 automatically removes NA values with a warning. Next time just try and see what happens.

Q5: Yes, you can. Use `geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE)`. Again, read the documentation.

Q6: By melting your data.frame. And using the variable names as a grouping variable. This is the recommended way. You could also do something like `+ geom_point(aes(y=PPP),shape=2)`

This site discourages multiple questions per post. You should also read the documentation and do some basic research (search the site and the web) before asking a question.

Comment: Thanks Roland, great help. ill keep the questions to a minimum